# Accessing windows files

Tags: bash, windows, files

I'm trying to access my Windows files from Ubuntu, and so far I was able to create a script that mounts the folder I want and have it on the system startup. I am able to list, delete, move, create files, but I'm not able to open them with VLC I get the error:

Your input can't be opened:

VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///home/tiago/Windows/Videos/Filmes/x-subterranea-720p.mkv'. Check the log for details.

Can someone help me identify what I'm doing wrong?

This is my Bash script:

```
!/bin/bash
sudo -S -k mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda3 /root/win
sudo -S -k mount --bind /root/win/Users/Tiago/ /home/tiago/Windows
```

One of the files I can't open:

```
root@tiago-X510UR:/home/tiago/Windows/Videos/Filmes# ls -l  ex-subterranea-720p.mkv
-rwxrwxrwx 2 root root 4693513161 set 23  2017 ex-subterranea-720p.mkv
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'open'? I would say that when you can view a file, you can open it (with the viewer). Are there problems only with multimedia files? In that case maybe you need to install the package `ubuntu-restricted-extras`.

Comment: VLC can't load the file. I get an error. If I copy the file to the local system folder I can open it with no problems

Comment: There might be a problem with ownership (of `/root/win` or `/home/tiago/Windows` or some subdirectory), so that VLC is not allowed to see the file. Please notice, that you should *not* run VLC with elevated permissions, so the file should be visible by the regular user ID (I guess it is 'tiago').

Comment: Maybe the following link can help you mount the Windows partition with suitable options, [Mount NTFS partition in a USB drive with custom permissions and owner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072)

Comment: i thought that by giving rwx to others would allow anyone to be able to open the file. vlc included

Comment: Yes, but some directory in the path might not have enough permissions. I tested with an NTFS file system in a USB pendrive and could make the difference depending on the ownership of the mountpoint. So I suggest that you try after changing ownership.

Comment: Thanks! I'm a real noob this is my first time doing this. I read the thread you sent but I was not able to understand the ownership part. Can you please help me on how I can change the ownership and what should I change it to?

Comment: I'll try, see the answer. Please ask for more details, if you need :-)

Answer (score 1):

I will copy and paste from my [previous AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11840/how-do-i-use-chmod-on-an-ntfs-or-fat32-partition/956072#956072) but skip some details, ...

- Unmount the NTFS partition ...
- Create a custom mountpoint ...
- Check your userID's `uid` number ...

**Mount the NTFS partition**

*Example 1* (without execute permissions for files, no access for 'others'),

```
sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdxn /mnt/sd1  # general syntax
sudo mount -o rw,user,uid=1000,dmask=007,fmask=117 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/sd1  # modify to match your case
```

This way I think the files and directories in the Windows partition (which I assume has an NTFS file system) should be readable (and writable) by the main user ID, with the number 1000 (and I guess the name 'tiago'). Modify if there is another user ID.

`dmask` is the mask for directories and `fmask` is the mask for files. These should be the octal inverse of the permissions that you want (770 and 660).

Check also that you point to the correct device (modify `/dev/sdb1` if necessary).

See `man mount` if you want more details about the mount options.

---

When this works (maybe after some modifications), you can put the commands into a file (make a bash shellscript), make it executable and run the shellscript in order to mount the Windows partition in a convenient way.